# Error on executing Python script in Google Cloud Function on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have created a google cloud function with following code in Node.js :

```
exports.hellogcspy1 = function (event, callback) { 
var PythonShell = require('python-shell'); 
const Bigquery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery'); 
const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage'); 
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn, 
    py    = spawn('python', ['my_script.py']); 
var options = { 
  mode: 'text', 
  pythonPath: '/usr/bin/python2.7', 
  pythonOptions: ['-u'], 
  scriptPath: '.', 
  args: ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'] 
}; 
PythonShell.run('my_script.py', options, function (err, results) { 
  if (err) throw err; 
  console.log('results: %j', results); 
}); 
};
```

I have installed all dependencies using -- npm install -- ....

```
package.json has following code :

{ 
  "name": "python-shell", 
  "version": "0.4.0", 
  "description": "to test python run", 
  "main": "Node.js", 
  "scripts": { 
    "test": "python my_script.py" 
  }, 
  "keywords": [ 
    "python" 
  ], 
  "author": "", 
  "license": "ISC", 
  "dependencies": { 
    "@google-cloud/bigquery": "^0.10.0", 
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^1.4.0", 
    "google-cloud": "^0.57.0", 
    "logging": "^3.2.0", 
    "numpy": "^0.0.1", 
    "python-shell": "^0.4.0" 
  }, 
  "repository": {}, 
  "devDependencies": {} 
}
```

and I have following imports in my_script.py :

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.bigquery import SchemaField
from google.cloud.iterator import HTTPIterator
from numpy import array
import uuid
from uuid import uuid4
from uuid import UUID
from subprocess import call
from subprocess import PIPE,Popen
from google.cloud import storage
```

when i do a test run of cloud function, it gives error on python script :

```
ImportError:no module called google.cloud
```

It is able to import other modules but not Google cloud modules and also the numpy module.I need to run this script whenever a new file arrives in bucket.Function is getting executed whenever a new file is loaded but failing while running loading script.I need to get it working in cloud function only as other methods like Object change notification,pub-sub requires external web link which is not currently allowed in organization. The script does not give this error while running directly from vm.
Can someone please help on how to resolve this ImportError issue ?

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to run Python code on Google Cloud Functions, you can use the recently-announced [Python runtime](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/python-runtime). You no longer need to use the Node.js hack. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because Google Cloud Functions doesn't have the google-cloud client libraries for Python installed.

I'm not a Python developer but the following approach should work:
Since you can upload any files you want as part of your function upload, you could include the google-cloud client library files in your upload and configure Python to use those. I'm not exactly how, perhaps by configuring PYTHONPATH using process.env.PYTHONPATH in your Node.js code.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer on this. I am also new to Python and node.js , so struggling to configure PYTHONPATH . Will update once I am able to configure it .